# How to get clicked element from multiple element with the same name different index index of array

Tags: jquery

I have a problem that. I have list of select option with same name but different index.
I don't know how to detect element when I click into one of them. 
Example:

```
<select name='contract_sides[0][joint_venture]'>
</select>
<select name='contract_sides[0][company_id]'>
</select>

<select name='contract_sides[1][joint_venture]'>
</select>
<select name='contract_sides[1][company_id]'>
</select>
...........
<select name='contract_sides[n][joint_venture]'>
</select>
<select name='contract_sides[n][company_id]'>
</select>
```

When I change value one of them. I will show/hide `<select name="contract_sides[index]company_id"></select>` below.
Thank you so much for your help. Sorry for my english !
P/s: The problem is simpler if we use the class but the problem is that we can only use the name.

Solution from Light:

```
$('select[name*="joint_venture"]').on('change', function () {    
  let name = $(this).attr('name');
  let index = name.match(/\[([0-9]*)\]/)[1];

  // Hide the company id
  $(`select[name="contract_sides[${index}][company_id]"]`).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select[name*="contract_sides"]').on('click', function () {
    // Your clicked element is now $(this)    
    let $this = $(this);

    // Name of the clicked element
    let name = $this.attr('name');

    // Index of the clicked element
    let index = name.match(/\[([0-9]*)\]/)[1];
});
```

Following your comment to another answer, I understand more what you were looking for, and I believe this should behave how you want

```
$('select[name*="joint_venture"]').on('change', function () {    
  let name = $(this).attr('name');
  let index = name.match(/\[([0-9]*)\]/)[1];

  // Hide the company id
  $(`select[name="contract_sides[${index}][company_id]"]`).hide();
});
```

Comment: If using this method, how can I distinguish whether the name has joint_venture and the name has company_id

Comment: $(this).attr('name') will give you the attribute value, and then you can use this in an if / else

Comment: Updated my code to give you the index of the clicked element as well - I can't quite figure out what you want to do past that, but I hope the index & names are enough for you to figure the rest out

Comment: I updated solution for this problem. I just want to say Thank You so much for helping me :D